# Why am I getting a duplicate string when I $push to an array in a document using mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to update a document using Poll.findOneAndUpdate() and $push to an array it seems to push 2 of the same string.

I tried combining the 2 Poll.findOneAndUpdate's I was doing before into one to see if that was the issue but it still pushes 2 strings.

before

```
var poll = await Poll.findOne({});
var choice = parseInt(message[1], 10);
var cIndex = choice - 1;
var cID = poll.choices[cIndex].id
var currV = poll.choices[cIndex].votes;
var i = currV + 1
var tUser = userstate.username

await Poll.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": poll.id, "choices.id": cID },
        { $push: { voters: tUser } }, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true }, (err, doc) => {

        })

await Poll.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": poll.id, "choices.id": cID },
        { $set: { "choices.$.votes": i } }, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true }, (err, doc) => {
          console.log(doc)
        })
```

after

```
var poll = await Poll.findOne({});
var choice = parseInt(message[1], 10);
var cIndex = choice - 1;
var cID = poll.choices[cIndex].id
var currV = poll.choices[cIndex].votes;
var i = currV + 1
var tUser = userstate.username

  await Poll.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": poll.id, "choices.id": cID },
        { $set: { "choices.$.votes": i }, $push: { voters: tUser } }, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true }, (err, doc) => {
          console.log(doc)
        })
```

They both output the desired result:

```
{ active: true,
  choices:
   [ { id: 'RPSSbjCmIZ', text: 'Yes?', votes: 0 },
     { id: 'kxNHYi4oXV', text: 'No', votes: 0 } ],
  voters: [ 'opti_21' ],
  _id: 5d8bdcc4de15a567143075a9,
  polltext: 'Tea? Hmmm',
  __v: 0 }
```

But if I check the document it shows:

```
{ active: true,
  choices:
   [ { id: 'IGPMUREdSP', text: 'Yes?', votes: 0 },
     { id: 'NDdrKIHQpE', text: 'No', votes: 0 } ],
  voters: [ 'opti_21', 'opti_21' ],
  _id: 5d8bd52fa7ccb866578cb38e,
  polltext: 'Tea? Hmmm',
  __v: 0 }
```

The $set for votes works fine for both ways. I just want it to push one string into the array so that if that user tries to vote again they won't be able to.

Here is the code in context of the whole app:
https://github.com/browemedia/vibey_bot/blob/50045043f410b13d0966c7f1c873fe6dd3b23905/server.js#L591

Answer (score 1):

use `$addToSet`

$`addToSet` do not add the item to the given field if it already contains it, on the other hand $`push` will add the given object to field whether it exists or not.

for more details [visit mongo $addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)